# Delete multiple lines with sed for nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, sed, lines

Hi there I'm trying to configure nginx with sed.

I want to delete the following block:

```
location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

**My first try:**

```
 sed '/location \/*\}/d' /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

This deletes nothing.

Could please anyone help?

Comment: I've got the answer :)

    sed '/location \//,/\}/d' /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

Found the answer here:
http://tweakandtune.blogspot.de/2013/03/linux-sed-multiple-lines.html

Comment: You can add that answer to your question and mark it accepted. That way people running across this question would know the answer as well as understand that this question is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want this:

```
sed -ri '/location \//,/.*\}/d' /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

   -r, --regexp-extended
      use extended regular expressions in the script (.*)

   -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
      edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed

Comment: Be careful with nested locations and complex rewrites.

Comment: You're welcome:) please note that if you want to change `nginx.conf` you need to use `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` to delete to `location` section.

```
awk '/^location/ {f=1} !f; /}$/ {f=0}' file
```

Or you can use the range function in `awk`, but I prefer the first due to more flexible.

```
awk '/^location/,/}$/ {next}1' file
```